# Loop in Python not working

Tags: python, loops

I'm having trouble getting a while loop to work here. What I would like to do is have the program jump back to "please enter the word you with to translate" once it runs and provides the output.

When I have used `while true` and `continue` in what I believe are the proper places, it simply continues to print the output. of the word I'm translating. Hope that makes sense.

Listed below is the code I have working. The second chunk is where I add the while loop and run into issues.

```
def silly_alpha():
    print("Looks like we're going with the Impossible alphabet.")
    word_trans = input('Please enter the word you wish to translate: ')
    if word_trans.isalpha():
        for letter in word_trans:
            print(impossible.get(letter.lower()), end=' ')
    else:
        print("There's no numbers in words. Try that again.")
```

This is the problematic code

```
def silly_alpha():
    print("Looks like we're going with the Impossible alphabet.")
    while True:
        word_trans = input('Please enter the word you wish to translate: ')
        if word_trans.isalpha():
            for letter in word_trans:
                print(impossible.get(letter.lower()), end=' ')
                continue
        else:
            print("There's no numbers in words. Try that again.")
            continue
```

Comment: You do not need to use `continue` at all.

Comment: What do you think continue do ?

Comment: The `continue` will continue with the most inner block. The `for` iteration in the `if` case and the `while` in the `else` case.

Comment: Mistook `continue` for `break`. Maybe `break` is what OP is looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have it repeat the loop, and accept a new word to translate, you simply need to remove those `continue` statements.  I tested this in IDLE and it works just fine.

```
def silly_alpha():
    print("Looks like we're going with the Impossible alphabet.")
    while True:
        word_trans = input('Please enter the word you wish to translate: ')
        if word_trans.isalpha():
            for letter in word_trans:
                print(impossible.get(letter.lower()), end=' ')
        else:
            print("There's no numbers in words. Try that again.")
```

However, you now have an infinite loop.  You may want to consider some way of allowing the user to enter a command that will terminate the loop.  Perhaps something like:

```
def silly_alpha():
    print("Looks like we're going with the Impossible alphabet.")
    while True:
        word_trans = input('Please enter the word you wish to translate, "x" to cancel: ')
        if word_trans == 'x':
            print('Exiting translation...')
            break
        elif word_trans.isalpha():
            for letter in word_trans:
                print(impossible.get(letter.lower()), end=' ')
        else:
            print("There's no numbers in words. Try that again.")
```

Comment: ahhhh this makes sense and is working. Thank you so much for the input!

Comment: while I do see the difference and see what has changed. Can you explain why place `while True` before `word_trans` makes the difference? When placed after it causes this looping issue, but when place before, it works as expected.

Comment: You repeatedly want to ask for an input, so each time the loop starts again you want to be able to enter something new, otherwise you can assign  `word_trans` once and then it just loops for the same `word_trans` over and over again.

Comment: Got it, that makes perfect sense and now it seems like a dumb question. 

Thanks so much for the answer and help with understanding that.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` applies to the closest loop and allow to skip next instructions in this loop.

So your first `continue` applies to `for`, as it s the last instruction of the loop, it as no effect.

You second `continue` applies to `while True`, as it s the last instruction of the loop, it as no effect.

What you are looking for is `break` which **terminates** the closest loop. In your case, the `while True` I suppose.

So remove the first `continue` and replace the second by a `break`.